# Wordpress - Only 1 image for 4 post Loop

Tags: wordpress, loops

Hi :) is possible to display on the loop, 4 news but only the first news show a image

Example
Image http://oi58.tinypic.com/ea09i9.jpg

My Code

```
 <?php $postslist = get_posts('category=14&showposts=4&order=DESC'); foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>src=<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>&w=120&h=74&zc=1&q=100" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/></a>
```

'

Comment: post the code of `catch_that_image` function

Comment: '


    function catch_that_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

Comment: @user3766356 Please edit your question if you want to add information and use the comments just to notify someone that you edited it. As you can see, code is... well... unreadable in the comments ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php 
        $i=1; 
        $postslist = get_posts('category=14&showposts=4&order=DESC'); 

        foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
?>
<?php 
        if($i%4==0 && $i==1) : ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>src=<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>&w=120&h=74&zc=1&q=100" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
            </a>
<?php 
        endif; 
?>  
<?php 
        $i++;
        endforeach; 
?>
```

// After taxonomy your code in implement but add your post type.

```
<?php
$i=1; 

$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre', 
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => 'news' 
        )
    ),
    'post_type'=>'',    //add your post type name 
    'posts_per_page' => 5, 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
);
    query_posts($args);
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
?>

 <?php 
        if($i%4==0 && $i==1) : ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>src=<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>&w=120&h=74&zc=1&q=100" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
            </a>
<?php 
        endif; 
?>  

<?php   
    $i++;
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Hi @ravipatel , my code is for a taxonomy as I can implement your code in this code?



`<?php
$args = array(
 'tax_query' => array(
  array(
   'posts_per_page' => 5,
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'taxonomy' => 'genre',
   'field' => 'slug',
   'terms' => 'news'


  )
 )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
 while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  $query->the_post();
  
   ?> 

               <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>src=<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>&w=100&h=102&zc=1&q=100" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358582/get-posts-from-custom-taxanomy/24358680#24358680